# Resumable upload returns Unauthorized when uploading chunk

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

Today I have a problem with the resumable upload feature of OneDrive via the Microsoft Graph API, as described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession). I have integration tests which previously worked, which now fail.

I successfully call `createUploadSession` and get an `uploadUrl` to use. I've replaced actual tokens with "XXX" here.

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/groups/273c2c33-8533-445d-ae65-4b63be296995/drive/root:/c2fa1a83-74f3-444b-9263-c9539ee3eae2.txt:/createUploadSession HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer XXX

{
  "item": {
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehaviour": "replace"
  }
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.uploadSession",
    "expirationDateTime": "2017-04-27T11:07:50.5650598Z",
    "nextExpectedRanges": ["0-"],
    "uploadUrl": "https://sageglodbizp.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointTests/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01LQXPMG56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ/uploadSession?guid='9d14ed72-e532-442e-94e8-70952b365527'&path='~tmp0B_c2fa1a83-74f3-444b-9263-c9539ee3eae2.txt'&overwrite=True&rename=False&access_token=XXX"
}
```

So the `uploadUrl` is there. Then, I try to PUT a chunk to this url but get a `401 Unauthorized` in response:

```
PUT https://sageglodbizp.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointTests/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01LQXPMG56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ/uploadSession?guid='9d14ed72-e532-442e-94e8-70952b365527'&path='~tmp0B_c2fa1a83-74f3-444b-9263-c9539ee3eae2.txt'&overwrite=True&rename=False&access_token=XXX HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer XXX
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

As I'm using the URL provided by the Graph API, I believe this to be a bug. I'm passing the same bearer token to the second call as the first (I've also tried it with no access token, given that one is in the  URL).

I have tried this with two different Office 365 tenants, both with the same result.

This has previously worked. Any thoughts on why this has stopped working? Is it correct that the `uploadUrl` points to my SharePoint endpoint rather than the Graph API?

I should also add, a non-resumable upload directly to the Graph API works fine.

Any suggestions most welcome.

**EDIT**:

This seems to be affected by the length of the filename to which you upload:

`myfile-123100000000000000000000000.txt` works successfully

`myfile-1231000000000000000000000000.txt` fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug by Microsoft and fixed on Saturday 29 / Sunday 30 April 2017.

Comment: do you have a link to the issue ?

Comment: @toussa no sorry, we just had this information in email, which said some data was added to the 'access_token' query parameter, which pushed the URLs over SharePoint's 2048 character limit. This is why it is affected by the filename length.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession#upload-bytes-to-the-upload-session):

> Including the Authorization header when issuing the PUT call may result in a HTTP 401 Unauthoized response. The Authoization header and bearer token should only be sent when issueing the POST during the first step. It should be not be included when issueing the PUT.

If you remove the `Authorization: Bearer XXX` header from your PUT call should resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi @Marc, thanks for your comment. I would say two things - first, while that is indeed specified in the documentation, it is easy to miss. I would argue that you should not change the behaviour of a live system in this way, which breaks code deployed to our customers. Secondly, when I remove the bearer token, I'm now getting a different error, again from code which previously worked - which I've raised http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663087/microsoft-graph-api-resumable-upload-returns-404-when-uploading-chunk

Comment: @Marc LaFleur - MSFT I'm having a similar issue here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197925/microsoft-graph-resumable-upload-url-returning-v2-onedrive-api-upload-url?noredirect=1#comment77363559_45197925