# Microsoft Graph Resumable Upload URL Returning V2 OneDrive API Upload URL

Tags: onedrive, sharepoint-api, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to use Microsoft Graph API to create a resumable upload through a REST call and I can receive a upload URL in return.  However, it's not at all like the documentation URL and seems to be an "older" non-Graph v2.0 API

https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm

In the example the return URL is

```
https://sn3302.up.1drv.com/up/fe6987415ace7X4e1eF866337
```

However, the one I receive is:

```
https://{server}/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01LFLHCDPPDY5LDTR3UREILVK4ISP2HJIE/uploadSession?guid='031a05ef-806e-4118-a5ff-8dea9b558c3e'&path='~tmp8B_test.xls'&overwrite=True&rename=False
```

Which is consistent with the OneDrive API differences. 
 https://dev.onedrive.com/direct-endpoint-differences.htm

But results in a 401 Unauthorized response with an error of

> Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException'
>   was thrown."

*I think* this is because the authentication is different and my MS-Graph access token is not valid when I put 'Authorization: Bearer {accesstoken}' in the header (that header works for all of my other REST calls via Graph)

**How can I get a Graph Upload URL to upload my file to OneDrive Business**?  Or **how can I get the return URL to work so I can upload to OneDrive Business**?

**Edit**:  TO SHOW PERMISSIONS

here's my permissions from the app.developers
[image]

And here's where I create the access token

```
request.setEndpoint('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        string body;
        body = '&client_id={clientId}';
        body += '&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default';
        body += '&client_secret={Secret}';
        body += '&grant_type=client_credentials';
```

**Here is where I'm making the API call for the upload session** (disregard the syntax):

```
webRequest.setEndPoint('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{myUserId}/drive/items/{parentItem_folder_Id}:/test.xls:/createUploadSession');
        webRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken());
        webRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        webRequest.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        webRequest.setHeader('Host', 'graph.microsoft.com');
        webRequest.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
        webRequest.setMethod('POST');
```

Comment: Can you clarify your environment? Are you attempting to use [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession) to create a resumeable upload session or are you using the OneDrive API? These are two seperate APIs and the way you call them differs.
Also, are you using pure REST or a .NET SDK?

Comment: Thank you for following up.  I edited my question for clarity.  This is the Graph API creating a resumable upload using pure REST calls.  My preference is to use Graph as much as possible

Comment: I also added the token refresh code (which works for all other REST calls) and the permissions from apps.dev.microsoft.com

Comment: I made a bit of headway finding this but it didn't fix the issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656203/microsoft-graph-api-onedrive-resumable-upload-returns-unauthorized-when-uplo/43660703#43660703

Comment: Could you add the HTTP call you're making to request the upload URI? It may help.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT How would I do that?

Comment: You're making an call tot he API that returns the upload URL. I'm interested in that call, not just the URL it returns.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I added that upload request code to the question

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but have you tried using `/me/` instead of `/users/{myUserId}/`?

Comment: I can't because this is a code-based flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you're attempting to upload files using without a user (i.e. an app-only rather than delegated scenario). While you're requesting the correct scope (`Files.ReadWrite.All`), this scenario is not currently supported. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession):

> **Note:** The Files.ReadWrite.All application permission is not yet supported on this API. Full support is planned soon.

At the moment, resumable uploads are only supported in delegated scenarios (i.e. where a user has directly authenticated and is uploading to their own drive).

Comment: I'm able to upload via the Simple Upload method:  webRequest.setEndPoint('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{myUser}/drive/items/{myfolderID}:/{MyFileName}:/content');

webRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + setaccesstoken());

webRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

webRequest.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

webRequest.setHeader('Host', 'graph.microsoft.com');

webRequest.setHeader('Content-Length', string.valueOf(file.contentsize));
webRequest.setMethod('PUT');

Comment: so the simple upload works using the bearer token, content type plaintext, accept JSON, host graph.microsoft.com, content length

Comment: Ahhhhh!  I see what you're saying.  For simple upload that Files.ReadWrite.All is implemented, where as for resumable (per the documentaiton) it's not

Comment: Is there a place where I can see the roadmap?

Comment: That is correct. App-only scenarios are only supported by the simple upload method at the moment. At this time the only roadmap guidance is the "available soon" note in the docs and I'm afraid I don't have an ETA yet.

Comment: is there anyway to delegate a user via a code flow?

Comment: Technically the problem here isn't the OAUTH workflow but rather using the app-only model. If you have the end-user interactively login to the service, you will be able to use resumable upload to _their own drive_. The scenario that isn't supported at the moment is uploading to other user's or group drives. In other words, `Files.ReadWrite` is supported, just not `Files.ReadWrite.All`.

Comment: What does "interactively" mean?  Does that mean they need to use a browser and there is no way to do it server-side?  if so, that's okay.  I just want to cover my bases.  Right now i'm using my personal one drive but allowing the app to authenitcate.

Comment: last question:  is there a way I can check the progress of that Files.ReadWrite.All implementation?  Then I'll know when it's available.

Comment: The best place to track changes is the [Change Log](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog). As to the authentication flow, you may want to check out [this post](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) I wrote a little while back. This walks you through the core "Login with Microsoft" workflow using v2 endpoint.

Comment: I'll check it out!  Thanks much and hope to see that feature soon!

Comment: will upload from URL be supported anytime soon?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_upload_url

Answer (score 1):

The 401 error is caused by using the "Authorization: Bearer" header when trying to use the URL returned after creating the upload session.  When you remove the authorization header you might still get an error.  For me it was a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: That is the exact error I got:  System.HttpResponse[Status=FORBIDDEN, StatusCode=403].  Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: No, not yet.  I just started a new question having to do with deleting the upload session.

Comment: Is your response URL in 2.0 OneDrive/Sharepoint API and not Graph?

Comment: Yes, it was "https://REDACTED.sharepoint.com/personal/...." instead of "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/...".

Comment: same with mine.  I was hoping to get the graph URL in the documentation.  I'd like to stay away from the API's that may be depricated over time.  Looks like Graph is the way of the future.  I'm wondering why it returns that way?  Is it a bug or something not yet implemented?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but here is the related question I opened.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219202/cannot-delete-an-upload-session

Comment: Microsoft requested that I add the issue to UserVoice.  https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/20300146-allow-createuploadsession-to-work-for-app-level-to

Comment: Cool!  I hope that expedites the creation of that permission.