# Cannot delete an upload session

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I can create an upload session, but I cannot delete it immediately afterwards.  I receive a 403 Forbidden error.

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required: https://REDACTED.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/15/error.aspx&Source=%2f_vti_bin%2fclient.svc%2fv2.0%2fdrives%2fREDACTED%2fuploadSession%3fguid%3d%27REDACTED%27%26path%3d%27%7etmpE6_test.txt%27%26overwrite%3dFalse%26rename%3dTrue
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Return_Url: https://REDACTED.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/error.aspx
X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.
ODATA-VERSION: 4.0
X-IDCRL_AUTH_PARAMS_V1: IDCRL Type="BPOSIDCRL", EndPoint="/personal/REDACTED/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/", RootDomain="sharepoint.com", Policy="MBI"
SPRequestGuid: REDACTED
request-id: REDACTED
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.6712
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: REDACTED Ref B: REDACTED Ref C: 2017-07-20T14:31:00Z
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 20 Jul 2017 14:31:00 GMT
Expires: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 14:31:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 20 Jul 2017 14:31:00 GMT
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Here is the stripped down version of the code that gets the same result.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace OneDriveUploadSession
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string strTokenURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/REDACTED.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token";
            string strAppSecret = "client_id=REDACTED&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=REDACTED&grant_type=client_credentials";
            string strUserName = "REDACTED";


            //Get Access Token
            WebClient wcAccessToken = new WebClient();

            wcAccessToken.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            string strJSONAccessToken = wcAccessToken.UploadString(strTokenURL, strAppSecret);
            dynamic dynJSONAccessToken = jss.DeserializeObject(strJSONAccessToken);
            string strAccessToken = dynJSONAccessToken["access_token"].Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");


            //Get Drive ID for specified user
            WebClient wcDriveID = new WebClient();

            wcDriveID.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + strAccessToken);

            string strDriveJSON = wcDriveID.DownloadString("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + strUserName + "/drives");
            dynamic dynDriveJSON = jss.DeserializeObject(strDriveJSON);
            string strDriveID = dynDriveJSON["value"][0]["id"];


            //Create Upload Session
            WebClient wcCreateUploadSession = new WebClient();
            string strCreateUploadSessionURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/" + strDriveID + "/root:/test.txt:/createUploadSession";

            wcCreateUploadSession.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + strAccessToken);
            wcCreateUploadSession.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

            string strJSONCreateUploadSession = wcCreateUploadSession.UploadString(strCreateUploadSessionURL, "POST", "{\"item\": {\"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior\": \"rename\"}}");
            dynamic dynJSONCreateUploadSession = jss.DeserializeObject(strJSONCreateUploadSession);
            string strUploadSessionURL = dynJSONCreateUploadSession["uploadUrl"];


            //Delete Upload Session
            WebRequest wrDeleteUploadSession = WebRequest.Create(strUploadSessionURL);

            wrDeleteUploadSession.Method = "DELETE";
            wrDeleteUploadSession.GetRequestStream();
            wrDeleteUploadSession.GetResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried uploaded some content prior to deleting? I suspect the problem here is that you've never sent any data so there isn't anything to delete.

Comment: Yes.  I get the same error though and the content doesn't upload.  I stripped down the code to do the bare minimum to make it easier to troubleshoot.  There is something to delete though.  A temporary file is created in that location on the user's OneDrive.  The delete method should remove that file.

Comment: I suspect that this is the reason it doesn't work.     https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/commit/98b5a9d94d17ae25765d0605b978f0c2ddff5cc9     It looks like they made some headway on it though because my code started magically working on July 7 and then stopped again on July 11.

Comment: Exactly what I was writing in my answer. :) App-only isn't support yet.

Comment: At the request of Microsoft, I've also added the issue to UserVoice.  https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/20300146-allow-createuploadsession-to-work-for-app-level-to

Comment: Got my vote :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you're using the client credentials flow (aka app-only). Resumable uploads are not supported in this scenario. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession):

> Note: The Files.ReadWrite.All application permission is not yet supported on this API. Full support is planned soon.

At this time, resumable uploads are only supported using delegated permission.